# Is KieSession.insert() and KieSession.fireAllRules() thread-safe?

Tags: spring, drools, jbpm

I am using **Drools** with **Spring Boot**. In my project, I am making singleton Beans of *KieSession*, *KieContainer* and *KieServices*. The KieSession will be used in different singleton services and controllers. I wanted to know whether `KieSesion.insert()` and `KieSession.fireAllRules()` are **thread-safe** with singleton bean implementations. Or should I create a utility class having **synchronized** access to KieSesion.insert() and KieSession.fireAllRules()?

Comment: You should be considering session pooling. I highly doubt the session is going to be threadsafe given how many array lists are used under the covers to manage facts and working memory -- this is just asking for a concurrent modification exception.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am wrapping the KieSession having ReentrantLock for synchronization. Should this be fine?

Comment: So you're trying to throttle your application so that rules can only be executed out of one bean at a time? Sounds really counterintuitive/wrong.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Actually I am implementing the KieSession with JPA persistence. Since KieSession isn't thread-safe, OptimisticLockException might occur, thereafter failing the entire JPA functionality of the KieSession. If the JPA functionality is down, then the recovery after application restart also fails. Only an application restart brings back the JPA functionaltiy. So I am thinking to throttle that with synchronization. What do you suggest?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas this is just plain wrong - see my answer. Please update your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KieSession` has been threadsafe since Drools 6, from the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.51.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_improved_multi_threading_behaviour)

> Engine’s code dealing with multi-threading has been partially
> rewritten in order to remove a large number of synchronisation points
> and improve stability and predictability. In particular this new
> implementation allows a clearer separation and better interaction
> between the User thread (performing the insert/update/delete actions
> on the session), the Drools engine thread (doing the proper rules
> evaluation) and the Timer one (performing time-based actions like
> events expiration).

Since `7.52.0.Final`, users can disable thread-safety if not needed to gain some performance. Here's the [relevant](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#thread-safety-option) release note:

> As per the default configuration, a KieSession is thread-safe and can
> be shared safely and used by multiple threads at the same time.
> However, if a KieSession is running, it requires additional
> synchronization points to support the thread-safety, which is not
> required, and eventually, it slows the performance of the KieSession.
> Therefore, a new ThreadSafeOption is introduced, which you can use to
> optionally disable the thread-safety. The ThreadSafeOption consists of
> two values including YES (default) and NO.

Comment: Also, could you please provide some suggestions on this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841081/persistent-aware-kiesession-not-using-pessimistic-lock-during-transactions

Comment: @sam yes I'll take a look at it